# Calculating group row at run time of a NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have a `NSTableView`, filled with song titles.

The songs are ordered by artists, so I can display the artist name as a row view.

[image]

---

### Code

Until now, I had to iterate through the table data and manually add the artists to the array.

```
NSMutableArray *songsAndArtists = [NSMutableArray array];

Artist *artist;
for (Song *song in self.songs) {
    if (artist != song.artist) {
        artist = song.artist;
        [songsAndArtists addObject:artist];
    }

    [songsAndArtists addObject:song];
}
```

---

This can be really slow if you have 1'000 - 5'000 songs.
I haven't really figured out how I could speed up this process.

Does anybody have an idea how to calculate this at runtime?

---

### EDIT

I'll try to clarify what I meant:

`NSTableView` supports **group rows**. My table view displays all the songs in CoreData.
I'd like to use the group rows to display the artist of the songs, like in the print screen I added above.

To do this I have to provide an array with an artist, followed by it's songs, followed by the next artist, and so on.

The code above shows how to insert the artists, but it's a pretty time-consuming process.

So my question, how can I speed this up?

---

### HINT

Like [nielsbot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/210171/nielsbot) and [Feloneous Cat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/742584/feloneous-cat) suggested, iterating through all the artists won't work for me.

The user also has the option to search though the library.
Therefore, not all the songs should actually appear in the list.

---

### Solution

I just want you to let you know what the problem was:

The problem was, that I actually compared via `NSString` in the previous version.
Pretty stupid fault...

It takes about **0.1 seconds or less** which is great:

```
tableData = [self addGroupRowsToArray:[self allSongs] withKeyPath:@"artist"];

- (NSArray *)addGroupRowsToArray:(NSArray *)array withKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath {
    NSMutableArray *mixedArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    id groupRowItem;
    for (id arrayItem in array) {
        if (groupRowItem != [arrayItem valueForKeyPath:keyPath]) {
            groupRowItem = [arrayItem valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
            [mixedArray addObject:groupRowItem];
        }

        [mixedArray addObject:arrayItem];
    }

    return mixedArray;
}
```

Comment: No, it's a `NSTableView`, group rows are supported since **10.7**.

Comment: But the algorithm would be the same for iOS and Mac OS X, so I figured I'd add both tags

Comment: This is not called in your datasource every time, or is it?

Comment: haha of course not. Only when loading the data

Comment: so you want a union of the list of unique songs and a list of unique artists? also, is `self.songs` already sorted? how?

Comment: ok i see--nstableview has no concept of sections, however you can display chosen rows as header cells..

Comment: @nielsbot I use Core Data, so I can sort it by `artist.name`.

Comment: So no inverse relationship `artist.songs`?

Comment: @nielsbot There is an inverse relationship

Comment: Just like you wrote, `artist.songs`

Comment: See my answer below. This applies to artist.songs (kinda the point I just didn't know you were using core data). BTW I'm currently doing this with a program I wrote for the iPhone so I can tell you it works like a champ with UITableView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, i've tried to reproduce your problem. I don't know where do you get data from so i've faked them just for performance test. I also tested the code on iPod 4gen, and it works without any lag. (tried either 50000 rows and it only hang upon start, then worked perfectly)

In general my approach differs from yours with data structures. So you use arrays, and i use dictionaries. Still i think if i used arrays there should be no issues anyway. Maybe i am getting wrong what you've asked?

Still, my approach seems to be better suitable for search to work(sry i've been too bothered to try to implement it). Indeed, now the search to take place, whole sections may be excluded without checking songs, unless you need to search songs of course, anyway this gives more flexibility.

okay here is a link: https://github.com/igorpakushin/BigList

will be glad to here some feedback,
thank you

regards,
Igor

Comment: Thanks, yes it only lags while calculating it, but if I filter the array i have to do the whole thing again.

Comment: Hey thank you! You actually pointed me into the right direction. It was a fault I made in my project, without this I wouldn't have taken a second look :)

Comment: Glad that helped :) Yet, I believe that if you really need this to work smoothly, you really have no other option then to do the searching in the background. See, the sorting does take significant time to finish, and that is what you can't really fix. So, say, I'd add some visibility flag to songs, and the filtering would affect this flag actually. While the search works maybe change the opacity of the iterated songs and move them away when it's done

Comment: But that is a "perfect" case I'd say. Well 5000 is not that much, you may have enough of what you've got

Comment: It's really fast enough. I've got about 3'000 rows in like 0.05 seconds. Mind blowing ;)

Comment: It's Core Data, the performance is just unbelievable, fetching and sorting is faster than the blink of an eye.

Comment: I believe that's because of the NSFetchRequest as nielsbot suggested? Should try that out!

Comment: Actually no, it's just a standard fetch. I'm on a SSD though, which speeds it up even more, of course.

Comment: Well, on the real device things will most likely be a lot worse then

Comment: It's not iOS, it a Mac OS X app

Comment: Ah, I see. Lol, well I think this is no issue then

Comment: a core data fetch reads from the persistent store, which reads the saved data from the hard disk

Comment: well, that sounds like it shortens your ssd's life, it is dependent on how much you write to it, would recommend against that - and only use ssd to start your mac quickly. Don't you have a swap on ssd?

Answer (score 3):

Is this faster?

```
-(NSArray*)songsAndArtists:(NSArray*)allArtists
{
    NSMutableArray * result = [ NSMutableArray array ] ;
    for( Artist * artist in allArtists )
    {
        [ result addObject:artist ] ;
        [ result addObjectsFromArray:artist.songs ] ;
    }
    return result ;
}
```

If you are getting "all artists" from Core Data, you can tell it to prefetch the objects in the songs relationship, which will speed things up further.

```
-(NSArray*)allArtists
{
    NSFetchRequest * request = [ NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Artist" ] ;
    [ request setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:@[ @"songs" ] ] ;
    ...
    return results ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It surely does run faster. But the problem is, that I have to be able to do the same through a filtered song list. So only the songs found by the search should appear in the list..

Comment: Oh--that's not part of the original question. You can modify the `songsAndArtists` method I gave, replacing `artist.songs` with a filtered list of songs... OR, use your original method for the search case.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to avoid such exceptions if possible. It seems odd to me that this is necessary...

Comment: For filtered array, again, have an array of artists. Each artist has an array of songs that match your filter. This keeps the mechanism the same.

Personally, I would keep the general case and the search case separate. However, nielsbot and myself have given you the answer to the original question. Adding searching (after the question has been answered) is feature creep and is unfair to those who answer your question.

Comment: @FeloneousCat I'm sorry but while creating the initial question I wasn't aware that filtering it would make a difference. It depends on the answer, which I couldn't know in advance.

Answer (score 3):

So, let's back up and look at what you REALLY have. You already have all the information that you need residing in songs. Why are you in essence duplicating it merely to break out the artist?

Think of it this way, if you have the following songs (song/artist)

```
(0)    "Death Eater", "Raging Machine Code"
(1)    "Interrupt",   "Raging Machine Code"
(2)    "Panic",       "Times Square Revolution"
(3)    "New Years",   "Times Square Revolution"
(4)    "Toast",       "Ed & Billy's Time Machine"
(5)    "Surge",       "Quiet Cat"
(6)    "Surveil",     "Quiet Cat"
```

What is wrong with this picture? We have the same information duplicated. Ideally, we want to have something like this:

```
"Raging Machine Code"     -> has an  array that contains
                             "Death Eater"
                             "Interrupt"
"Times Square Revolution" -> has an array that contains
                             "Panic"
                             "New Years"
"Ed & Billy's Time Machine" -> array that contains
                             "Toast"
"Quiet Cat"               -> array that contains
                             "Surge"
                             "Surveil"
```

For UITableView this makes things trivial - we tell it how many sections (four) and for each section how many songs. To generate the cell, we get an NSIndexPath that tells us the section and the row (section would be the artist and the row would be the song for that artist).

NSTableView doesn't do that. It gives us a row. However, if we do some work on the front end (i.e. the song list) then we can assure that life will be beautiful and fast (or at least faster). The key is to pre-calculate the number of songs per artist and store it.

So assume we are asked to display row 5. "Raging Machine Code" is 0-2 (artist, song, song). "Times Square Revolution" is 3-5. Ah! 5 is the last song, so we display "New Years"!

Try another one, assume we are to display row 6. "Raging..." was 0-2, "Times..." was 3-5, "Ed & Billy's" is 6-7. Bingo, we need to display the artist, "Ed & Billy's Time Machine"!

The idea is that we do much of this prework AHEAD of actually displaying the data. Looping through artists will be far faster than looping through ALL the songs. Plus now you are only doing simple math - no need to move things.

Sometimes how you store your data means the difference between success and failure. Whenever you see yourself having to "redefine a data structure" that usually means your data structure is faulty - it may be simple, but it causes more effort.

Hopefully this was helpful and didn't end up being "TLTR" (too long to read).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.You're right, it does run faster by iterating the artists, rather than the songs. But the problem is, that I have to be able to do the same through a filtered song list. So only the songs found by the search should appear in the list..

Comment: What I was showing you was NOT how to iterate through the artists - what I was showing you was how to display the data as required by an NSTableView that didn't require a time consuming spin to reformat the data.  What I showed you was how to calculate this at run time (as you originally asked). However to do so, you must store your data differently. BTW this will work on a filtered list too. I guess I'm a little puzzled why this doesn't work for you?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you mean.

Comment: "The key is to pre-calculate the number of songs per artist and store it." I understand, but I would still have to iterate through them, which would be exactly as time consuming if I scroll through the objects at the bottom of the table view.

Comment: At least if I filter the songs and I'm not sure how many songs of an artists are in the list

Comment: Think of it this way. In iOS, UITableView would work with artist and artist.songs (because artist would be your sections and songs would be the rows in the section). In OS X, however, you don't have sections, just rows. So you have to INFER the sections via the example I provided above.

Comment: But you don't NEED to iterate. You already get the songs via artist.songs. Why not continue to use that structure? Turning it into another data structure is actually making things harder, not easier (as you may have noticed by the time delay).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22211/discussion-between-feloneous-cat-and-nsaddict)

Comment: Really, you could apply a binary tree over what you are proposing--then you could quickly look up a row by it's index. Also, you could remember which node of the tree you looked up last--it's likely that the next lookup will be very close to the previous one. All the tree is really doing is memoizing index -> song index.